# How do I return information to javascript function in Objective-C?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

Let's say I have a UIWebView with some javascript functions. I want those javascript functions to be able to request information from my app and my app should return it. I am able to get the requests using [URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18) however, I don't know how to return the information back to the javascript function.

Is injecting a javascript variable into the UIWebView, then calling the javascript function again with the variable as a parameter the best way to do it? Or are there methods I can use for UIWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asynchronous communication.  Have a Javascript function for the Objective C routine to call back into the Javascript with any reply parameters required.  The Javascript callback function can even be one of the parameters sent to Objective C code via a URL scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Injecting Javascript via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is absolutely fine.

The other direction would be better handled via `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

[How to Properly Call ObjectiveC From Javascript](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/) (incl. Callback to JS) describes it in detail, sources are included.

Sample JS-code which makes use of the Objective-C returnValue:

```
NativeBridge.call("objCMethod", ["firstArgument"], function (returnValue) {
    if (returnValue) {
      // whatever
    } else {
      // whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: I already have this part working. My question was, how to return information to the javascript function. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: On the Objective C side of the code, how do I return the value to the script you posted? Can I just use the regular return key? For example: `-(BOOL)objCMethod:(NSString *)myString { //Do stuff... return YES; }`. Then in the javascript, `returnValue` will have the value "YES" right?

Comment: There _could_ be a method like `-(BOOL)objCMethod:(NSString *)myString`. But there's actually more code involved. In that sample project (http://blog.techno-barje.fr/public/iphone-sdk/NativeBridge/NativeBridge-non-buggy.zip) take a look at `webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, `handleCall` and `returnResult`.